# Displaying a Xamarin Forms StackList doesn't render properly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

While learning how to use Xamarin Forms and `StackLayouts` I'm having trouble rendering the items.

I'm trying to bind a collection of somethings to a `StackLayout`. The binding (more or less) works. The visual render is wrong.

For this question, I've picked some random thing (in this case, credit cards) to highlight my experimenting.

This is what I'm rending:

[image]

Notice how each custom row looks to be fixed height's or something?

Show me the code! Ok, so this is what I've done:

First, the page:

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        var creditCards = new SomeFakeListOfCreditCards();
        var stackLayout = new CreditCardStackLayout(creditCards);
        Contet = stackLayout;
    }
}
```

Now for the custom control...

```
public class CreditCardStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public CreditCardStackLayout(IEnumerable<CreditCard> creditCards)
    {
        // Note: credit cards can be null (because we don't have any).
        CreateContent(creditCards);
    }

    private void CreateContent(IEnumerable<CreditCard> creditCards)
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        Children.Add(TitleLabel);

        if (creditCards == null)
        {
            Children.Add(NoCreditCardLabel);
        }
        else
        {
            Children.Add(CreateCreateCardList(creditCards));
        }
    }

    private static ListView CreateCreateCardList(IEnumerable<CreditCard> creditCards)
    {
        if (creditCards == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("creditCards");
        }

        // Project the credit cards into a list view model.
        var viewModel = creditCards.Select(x => new CreditCardViewModel(x));

        return new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = viewModel,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CreditCardViewCell))
        };
    }

    private Label TitleLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return new Label
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = "A list of credit cards"
            };
        }
    }

    private Label NoCreditCardLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return new Label
            {
                Text = "You have no real credit cards on file."
            };
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good.. Now for the binding..

```
public class CreditCardViewCell : ViewCell
{
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        var stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = new Color(46, 81, 163),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children =
            { 
                NameLabel, 
                TypeImage, 
                NumberLabel, 
                ExpiresOnLabel,
                RemoveButton
            }
        };

        View = stackLayout;
    }

    private Label NameLabel
    {
        get
        {
            var label = new Label
            {
                FontSize = 14
            };

            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

            return label;
        }
    }

    private Label NumberLabel
    {
        get
        {
            var label = new Label
            {
                FontSize = 14
            };

            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Number");

            return label;
        }
    }

    private Label ExpiresOnLabel
    {
        get
        {
            var label = new Label
            {
                FontSize = 14
            };

            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "ExpiresOn");

            return label;
        }
    }

    private Image TypeImage
    {
        get
        {
            var creditCardModel = (CreditCardViewModel)BindingContext;
            string fileName = null;
            switch (creditCardModel.Type)
            {
                case "Visa":
                    fileName = "visa.png";
                    break;
                default:
                    fileName = "mastercard.png";
                    break;
            }

            var image = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromFile("Icons/" + fileName)
            };

            return image;
        }
    }

    private Button RemoveButton
    {
        get
        {
            var button = new Button
            {
                //Image = "Icons/remove.png"
                Text = "Remove"
            };
            button.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                // TODO when I figure out how to do this stuff.
                int i = 0;
                i++;
            };

            return button;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Also, please do not suggest going to a XAML file, I'm trying to learn this stuff programmatically.

Side thought: I wish I could turn on borders so I can see how things are laid out.

Comment: You (probably) need to set a HeightRequest value on your ViewCell, the layout engine is getting confused trying to compute the correct height for each cell, causing them to overlap.

Comment: so there's no auto-height setting (which I just assumed was the default -> no fixed height ... just the height of the `ViewCell`) ?

Comment: In my experience you need to play around with it some.  Ideally it would auto-calculate the height - but with ViewCell containing StackLayout I don't know that it's reliable without some hints.  You may also need to set HasUnevenRows on your ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ListView`'s `HasUnevenRows` property. Change this:

```
return new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = viewModel,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CreditCardViewCell))
};
```

to:

```
return new ListView
{
    HasUnevenRows = true,
    ItemsSource = viewModel,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CreditCardViewCell))
};
```

By default Xamarin.Forms `ListView` row size is fixed and set to the same value for every row (`RowHeight` property). With this configuration row auto-sizing won't work, but it also gives best `ListView` performance.

You can auto-size rows by setting ListView's `HasUnevenRows` property to true. It allows modifying `ViewCell` size by setting `ViewCell`'s `RowHeight` property (eg. in OnBindingContextChanged override). In newer Xamarin.Forms versions it also sizes ViewCells automatically (on older it worked only on Android).

Comment: Hi @danielLuberda - can you please add an explanation in the answer (above) to _why_ I should add that? What does that property mean/do, please?

Comment: Another quick question - if I do not set the `RowHeight` property, what value will it get set at? does it calculate the row height of the first cell and assumes that for the rest?

Comment: If you have HasUnevenRows = true it will do auto-sizing, if HasUnevenRows = false it's set to some default constant value, it doesn't calculate anything.